# TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have been having this issue for a while now and I cant seem to fix it. My web app was working fine until I started getting this error few weeks ago when I wanted to add some functionality. I do not know what the issue might be as I am still new to ReactJS and even with attempts to reset back to the last working commit, the problem still persists. I need help to fix it. I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined

every time i run my app. It says the error is in my selector file which is the one below and specifacally in the **selectCartItemsCount** block.

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const selectCart = (state) => state.cart;

export const selectCartItems = createSelector(
    [selectCart],
    (cart) => cart.cartItem
);

export const selectCartHidden = createSelector(
    [selectCart],
    (cart) => cart.hidden
);

export const selectCartItemsCount = createSelector([selectCartItems], (cartItems) => 
    cartItems.reduce(
        (accumulatedQuantity, cartItem) => 
            accumulatedQuantity + cartItem.quantity, 
        0
    )
);
```

I export this selector to my component which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';

import { toggleCartHidden } from '../../Redux/Cart/cart.actions';
import { selectCartItemsCount } from '../../Redux/Cart/cart.selectors';

import { ReactComponent as ShoppingIcon } from '../../Assets/shopping-bag.svg';

import './cart-icon.scss';

const CartIcon = ({ toggleCartHidden, itemCount }) => (
    <div className="cart-icon" onClick={toggleCartHidden}>
        <ShoppingIcon className="shopping-icon" />
        <span className="item-count">{itemCount}</span>
    </div>
);

const mapSateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    itemCount: selectCartItemsCount,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    toggleCartHidden: () => dispatch(toggleCartHidden()),
});

export default connect(mapSateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CartIcon);
```

My cart reducer looks like this:

```
import CartActionTypes from './cart.types';
import { addItemToCart, removeItemFromCart } from './cart.utils';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    hidden: true,
    cartItems: [],
};

const cartReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CartActionTypes.TOGGLE_CART_HIDDEN:
            return {
                ...state,
                hidden: !state.hidden,
            };

        case CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEMS:
            return {
                ...state,
                cartItems: addItemToCart(state.cartItems, action.payload),
            };

        case CartActionTypes.REMOVE_ITEM:
            return {
                ...state,
                cartItems: removeItemFromCart(state.cartItems, action.payload),
            };

        case CartActionTypes.CLEAR_ITEM_FROM_CART:
            return {
                ...state,
                cartItems: state.cartItems.filter(
                    (cartItem) => cartItem.id !== action.payload.id
                ),
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default cartReducer;
```

The function used to add items to the cart is:

```
export const addItemToCart = (cartItems, cartItemToAdd) => {
    const existingCartItem = cartItems.find(
        (cartItem) => cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
    );

    if (existingCartItem) {
        return cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
            cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
                ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1 }
                : cartItem
        );
    }

    return [...cartItems, { ...cartItemToAdd, quantity: 1 }];
};
```

Comment: I don't feel like there's enough information here to answer your question. Have you tried setting breakpoints or console.logging to make sure `cartItems` is defined, and is an array, before you call `.reduce` on it?

Comment: It might be because its an async task , and perhaps the  `cartItems ` have not been fetched from the backend as it is only fetched after the mounting (and even defined after the async process completes I believe but before that happens , your site crashes .) I think solution should be  Either provide it with an initial value of empty array or make a chek each usage of the variable.,\.

Comment: Hello @TKoL, so yeah the array before is an input selector where I get my cartItems from. I also have a middleware called redux-logger that records previous states before actions happen and states after actions happen. I did not have any item in the cart before it crashed, so i dont see any log of the cart.

Comment: What do you get when you ```console.log(cartItems)```?

Comment: Hello @AnkushVerma, so in my reducer, the initial cartItems state is an empty array and is only populated after items are pushed in. Any other solutions?

Comment: Could you include the code for how the ```cartItems``` gets its value?

Comment: @yuRa, I have included my reducer and function that adds items to the cart in the question...check it out

Comment: Since your app crashes on loading only, we dont really need to be worried about reducers. It must be the `selectCartItems` .Could you `console.log({accumulatedQuantity, quality:cartItem.quantity})` ? Also , use 'redux-logger' as middleware (if you can) for better visibility for debugging.

Comment: @AnkushVerma, I have redux-logger...and my cart items are undefined, according to it

Comment: Add a check of `cartItems?cartitems.map.....:[]`